# Client crashes when using "orbital" distances

Tags: gazebo-11, ogre

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to simulate things at large (e.g. "orbital" distances, up to ~10^11 m), and the client crashes as soon as any changes to the gui camera are made (e.g. trying to move the trackball position or orbit around a followed model. I get the following error, indicating that some function is trying to set a `NaN` value, but not much else.

```
[INFO] [gazebo_spawner]: process has finished cleanly [pid 2177018]
[gzclient   -2] gzclient: /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:405: virtual void Ogre::Node::setPosition(const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `!pos.isNaN() && "Invalid vector supplied as parameter"' failed.
[gzclient   -2] Aborted (core dumped)
[ERROR] [gzclient   -2]: process has died [pid 2177016, exit code 134, cmd 'gzclient   '].
```

My best guess is that the `float` values used by Ogre and other parts of the Gazebo client are overflowing. That said, I would have expected a standard 32bit float to support values up to ~10^38 m, so perhaps I've misdiagnosed the issue.

Scaling things down seems to avoid this particular error, but it's not ideal from my perspective. It would be nice to either be able to change the units used by the renderer (e.g. to km or Mm) or to somehow compile Gazebo to use `double` precision. Are either of those possible?

Is anyone aware of this issue and of any fixes?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27276/client-crashes-when-using-%22orbital%22-distances/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47307/shonigmann/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, it looks like supporting 64bit floats on the renderer/client side would be non-trivial.

Instead, we have found the preferred approach to be changing the frame of reference of the simulation to center about the vehicle, and using scaled models of celestial bodies at scaled distances. NASA's Intelligent Robotics Group has published a plugin that does just this on their github ([here](https://github.com/nasa/irg_open/tree/master/irg_gazebo_plugins/src/IRGCelestialBodyPlugin))

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47307/shonigmann/) with karma: 16 on 2021-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0